# How do I read a UTF8 encoded INI file?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-2010

I have an INI file in UTF-8 format.

I am using Delphi 2010 to read the INI file and populate a TStringGrid with the values in the INI file.

```
var
  ctr : Integer;
  AppIni : TIniFile;
begin
  AppIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.ini');
    for ctr := 1 to StringGrid1.RowCount do begin
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,ctr] := AppIni.ReadString('Column1','Row'+IntToStr(ctr),'');
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,ctr] := AppIni.ReadString('Column2','Row'+IntToStr(ctr),'');
    end;
  AppIni.Free;
```

The problem is that the unicode characters are appearing in the TStringGrid displaying 2 characters, rather than the 1 unicode character.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You can use [`TMemIniFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile) which has in one of its [`constructor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.Create) overloads `Encoding` parameter. Into this parameter you'll just pass `TEncoding.UTF8`. The rest of your code will remain same. Btw. try to learn how to use `try..finally` block to make sure the `AppIni` object will be released after its use.

Comment: Here's [`the code`](http://pastebin.com/nX0PAZNw) I was talking about.

Answer (score 17):

The `TIniFile` class is a wrapper of the Windows API for INI files. This does support Unicode INI files, but only if those files are encoded as UTF-16. Michael Kaplan has more details here: [Unicode INI function; Unicode INI file?](http://www.siao2.com/2006/09/15/754992.aspx)

So, you are out of luck with `TIniFile`. Instead you could use `TMemIniFile` which allows you to [specify an encoding in its constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.Create). The `TMemIniFile` class is a native Delphi implementation of INI file support. There are various pros and cons between the two classes. In your situation, only `TMemIniFile` can serve your needs, so it's looking like its pros are going to outweigh its cons.

Comment: David H says "only if those files are encoded as UTF-16", yet TLama says "you'll just pass TEncoding.UTF8".  So which is it?

Comment: I have tried using TMemIniFile instead of TIniFile, yet when I try to save a new INI, the file never gets created. Here's the create:  AppUnicodeINI := MemIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
    'test.ini',TEncoding.Unicode);   And here is the write method:  AppUnicodeINI.WriteString('Column1','Row'+IntToStr(ItemNo),StringGrid1.Cells[0,ctr]); Then finally AppUnicodeINI.Free;   Yet no file is created.

Comment: Both of us are correct. TLama says pass `TEncoding.UTF8` to `TMemIniFile`. And I say that too. That's my second paragraph. And I also say in paragraph 1 that you cannot use `TIniFile` because it only supports UTF-16. Note that `TMemIniFile` and `TIniFile` are not the same class. I think that's where you are confused.

Comment: I understand that I cannot use TIniFile.  Where I am confused is that TLama made reference to UTF8, whereas you said UTF16.  Moreover, using either with TMemIniFile still produces no output.  UTF8 is not UTF16.

Comment: Eureka! Looks like someone forgot to tell me to insert UpdateFile into my code, else nothing will get written to disk!  :-(

Comment: @user1527613, nobody forgot to tell you how to flush `TMemIniFile` to disk just because you've started your question with *"I am using Delphi 2010 to read the INI file"* as well as you were obviously only reading values from the INI file in your sample code. The question you've asked is answered here.

Comment: Well, as @TLama says, you said you were reading from the file. You did not ask how to write. Anyway, the documentation says this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile

Comment: @user1527613 Are you looking for more than this answer?

Comment: Which are the drawbacks for TMemIniFile?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you elaborate on the cons of reading INI files with TMemIniFile? For me nothing comes to mind...

Comment: @AloisHeimer I don't know of any.

Answer (score 3):

```
Uses IniFiles;

const
  SZ_APP_NAME = 'demo_test';

Procedure TForm1.GetSettings;
var
  _MemIniU: TMemIniFile;
  _SettingsPath: string;
begin
  try
    _SettingsPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + SZ_APP_NAME + PathDelim;
    if ForceDirectories(_SettingsPath) then
    begin
      _MemIniU := TMemIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(_SettingsPath,
        'Settings.ini'), TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        if _MemIniU.ReadInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', -1) = -1 then
          Form1.Position := poScreenCenter
        else
        begin
          Form1.Left := _MemIniU.ReadInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', 10);
          Form1.Top := _MemIniU.ReadInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowTop', 10);
          Form1.Width := _MemIniU.ReadInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowWidth', 594);
          Form1.Height := _MemIniU.ReadInteger(SZ_APP_NAME,
            'WindowHeight', 342);
        end;
          Edit1.Text := _MemIniU.ReadString(SZ_APP_NAME, 'UnicodeText', 'ąčę');
      finally
        _MemIniU.Free;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      MessageDlg(PWideChar(E.Message), TMsgDlgType.mtError,
        [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;

Procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
var
  _MemIniU: TMemIniFile;
  _SettingsPath: string;
begin
  try
    _SettingsPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + SZ_APP_NAME + PathDelim;
    _MemIniU := TMemIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(_SettingsPath, 'Settings.ini'),
      TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      if Form1.WindowState <> TWindowState.wsMaximized then
      begin
        _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', Form1.Left);
        _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowTop', Form1.Top);
        _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowWidth', Form1.Width);
        _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowHeight', Form1.Height);
        _MemIniU.WriteString(SZ_APP_NAME, 'UnicodeText', Edit1.Text);
      end;
      _MemIniU.UpdateFile;
    finally
      _MemIniU.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      MessageDlg(PWideChar(E.Message), TMsgDlgType.mtError,
        [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In an application were I was using `TIniFile` i had the need to start storing  Unicode chars.

To do this i simply changed the variable type from `TIniFile` to `TMemIniFile` and in the constructor, after the filename i added the second parameter `TEncoding.UTF8`.
Then before freeing the object i called `UpdateFile`. If Ini File is opened for reading, call to `UpdateFile` is not needed.

```
// ANSI version
var myIniFile: TIniFile;
begin
  myIniFIle := TIniFile.Create('c:\Temp\MyFile.ini');
  myIniFile.WriteString(par1,par2,par3);
  // [...]
  myIniFile.Free;
end


// Unicode version
//1) "Mem" added here
var myIniFile: TMemIniFile; 
begin
  // 2) Enconding added
  myIniFIle := TIniFile.Create('c:\Temp\MyFile.ini', TEncoding.UTF8); 
  myIniFile.WriteString(par1,par2,par3);
  // [...]
  // 3) call to UpdateFile to save to disc the changes
  myIniFile.UpdateFile; 
  myIniFile.Free;
end
```

The good news is that `UpdateFile` causes the ini file to be saved with the proper encoding, this means that if a ini file encoded in `ANSI` already exists it is overwriten so it becomes `UTF-8`, so the transaction between `ANSI` and `UTF-8` is smooth and not painful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Citing the answer above by David Heffernan, there is no need to use TMemIniFile provided the INI-files are UTF-16.
A draw back with TMemIniFile is, that TMemIniFile.UpdateFile deletes any header of the INI-file unless subordinate a square bracketed [Header].

In short, you will need no more than adding this file conversion to your code, and your standard INI-file read/write will support Unicode (no need for TEncoding.UTF8):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  slINItemp: TStringList;
begin
  if FileExists('MyINIfile.ini') then
    Try
      slINItemp := TStringList.Create;
      slINItemp.LoadFromFile('MyINIfile.ini'));
      slINItemp.SaveToFile('MyINIfile.ini',TEncoding.Unicode);
      slINItemp.Free;
    except
    end;
  ...
end;
```

Tested on Windows 7(32-bit) and Windows 10(64-bit) created with Delphi 10.4.2.

Otherwise, you may just convert existing INI-files with e.g. Notepad.exe, and your existing (Unicode enabled) application may suddenly benefit from Unicode supporting INI-files.